# chaining promises with ramdajs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm kinda of a beginner with Ramdajs and I'm trying to figure out how to chain promises with it.

so I have two functions; one of which fetches data as an array of objects from mongoDB as such:

```
  async getMongoDBMaterials(): Promise<Material[]> {
    return this.materialsRepository.find({});
  }
```

another of which fetches data also as an array of objects from a REST api as such:

```
  getCMSMaterials(): Promise<CMSMaterial> {
    const response = lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .get(`${this.apiUrl}/materials`)
        .pipe(map((resp) => resp.data)),
    );
    return response;
  }
```

I'm handling it currently like this which is pretty imperative in my opinion:

```
    const mongoDBMaterials = await this.getMongoDBMaterials();
    const CMSMaterial = await this.getCMSMaterials();
```

and then merging them both with a `mergeResponse(cmsList, mongoList)`

```
  private mergeResponse = R.curry((cmsList, mongoList, key = '_id') => {
    const omitKeys = R.compose(R.map, R.omit);
    const merged = mongoList.map((item, i) => {
      const parsed = Object.assign({}, item, cmsList[i]);
      return parsed;
    });
```

I'm trying to chain the promises using either `R.pipe()` or `R.compose()` in order to de-clutter the code a bit.

I tried this but i'm getting a `Promise { <pending> }` where i'm logging `x`

```
    const finishedMaterials = R.pipe(
      () => this.getMongoDBFinishes(),
      (val) => Promise.resolve(val),
      R.map((x) => console.log('Y', x)),
      (x) => console.log('X', x),
      Promise.all.bind(Promise),

      // (x) => this.mergeResponse()(getCMSFinishes),
    );
```

any help to turn this into ramda is welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that takes multiple promises, waits for them to fulfill using `Promise.all()`, and then applies the logic using `R.andThen`:

```js
const { pipe, unapply, andThen, transpose, map, mergeAll } = R

const fn = pipe(
  unapply(Promise.all.bind(Promise)), // wait for an array of promises
  andThen(pipe( // your logic here
    transpose,
    map(mergeAll)
  ))
)

// Example
const getMongoDBMaterials = () => Promise.resolve([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }])
const getCMSMaterials = () => Promise.resolve([{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }])

fn(getMongoDBMaterials(), getCMSMaterials())
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Your `mergeResponse` function accepts a list of arguments, while the result of `Promise.all()` is an array. Use `R.apply` to enable the function use an array as a list of arguments:

```js
const { pipe, unapply, andThen, transpose, map, mergeAll, curry, mergeLeft, apply } = R

const mergeResponse = curry((cmsList, mongoList) =>
  mongoList.map((item, i) => mergeLeft(item, cmsList[i]))
);

const fn = pipe(
  unapply(Promise.all.bind(Promise)), // wait for an array of promises
  andThen(apply(mergeResponse))
)

// Example
const getMongoDBMaterials = () => Promise.resolve([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }])
const getCMSMaterials = () => Promise.resolve([{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }])

fn(getMongoDBMaterials(), getCMSMaterials())
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: very cool, thanks! I was wondering how exactly I could add the `mergeResponse(cmsList, mongoList)` function in the `andThen(pipe(...` I tried adding it as `mergeResponse` but it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` i'm obviously missing something here

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there are several different problems with your approach.

Some of this has to do with the attempt to merge functional code inside an object-oriented block.  This looks odd to my eye:

```js
  getCMSMaterials(): Promise<CMSMaterial> {
    const response = lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .get(`${this.apiUrl}/materials`)
        .pipe(map((resp) => resp.data)),
    );
    return response;
  }
```

I would much rather use a pure function such as

```js
  const getCMSMaterials = (service, apiUrl) => lastValueFrom (
    service .get (`${apiUrl}/materials`) .pipe (map ((resp) => resp .data)),
  )
```

and then call it from a class method if necessary with

```js
  async someMethod (args) {
    //...
    return getCMSMaterial (this .httpService, this .apiUrl)
  }
```

Then you have

> ```js
> const mongoDBMaterials = await this.getMongoDBMaterials();
> const CMSMaterial = await this.getCMSMaterials();
> ```
>
> and then merging them both with a `mergeResponse(cmsList, mongoList)`

Are `cmsList` and `CMSMaterial` supposed be the same reference?

Next is

```js
  private mergeResponse = R.curry((cmsList, mongoList, key = '_id') => {
    const omitKeys = R.compose(R.map, R.omit);
    const merged = mongoList.map((item, i) => {
      const parsed = Object.assign({}, item, cmsList[i]);
      return parsed;
    });
```

Assuming that you just skipped the `return` statement at the end, this function defines but doesn't use the string `key` and the function `omitKeys`.  And if you're going to be using Ramda, then `Object.assign({}, item, cmsList[i])` might as well be written `mergeRight (item, cmsList [i])`

But the big problem is in the pipeline you create:

```js
const finishedMaterials = R .pipe (
  () => this.getMongoDBFinishes(),
  (val) => Promise.resolve(val),
  R.map((x) => console.log('Y', x)),
  (x) => console.log('X', x),
  Promise.all.bind(Promise),

 // (x) => this.mergeResponse()(getCMSFinishes),
);
```

First of all, you have a list of functions passed to `pipe`, and you name the result like it's a data object (`finishedMaterials`).  But `pipe` *always* returns a function.

Second, `() => this.getMongoDBFinishes()` will return **a Promise** for an array of `Material`s.  That means that following it up with `(val) => Promise.resolve(val)` is useless.  In [a better world](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land), this would result in a `Promise` for a `Promise` of an array of `Materials`, but the design of `Promise`s is that this collapses back into the original `Promise`.  It adds nothing.

Next is `R.map((x) => console.log('Y', x))`.  `console .log` returns an `undefined` value, so this `map` from `n` elements will do some logging and return an array of `n` `undefined` values.  There is a Ramda function, [`tap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap) which can be used to add such side-effects without impeding the `pipe` flow.

After that is another `console .log`, this one directly in the pipeline, so the next function will simply receive `undefined`.

Then you call `Promise.all.bind(Promise)`.  There's nothing particularly wrong with this, but since you have all sorts of anonymous functions anyway, I think it would be cleaner to write `(...xs) => Promise .all (xs)`, or to extract that into a utility function, perhaps `allPromises`.

The trouble is that only one value flows down a pipeline.  After the first function, which can have multiple inputs, every function can have a single input and a single output, but you want the results of both of your service calls to be passed into here.  While there are tricks you can do to make this work, it's something of an abuse of pipelines.

If we were to get all these things fixed, there is still a design problem that would bother me.  You are collecting data from two presumably independent sources, and then want to combine them as though they're guaranteed to return arrays of the same length.  I would find this quite worrisome.

---

Onto a solution.  Ori Drori already gave a reasonable answer.  Here's a somewhat different one:

```js
const getMongoDBMaterials = () => Promise .resolve ([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }])
const getCMSMaterials = () => Promise .resolve ([{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }])

const getAll = () =>
  Promise .all ([getMongoDBMaterials (), getCMSMaterials ()])
    .then (apply (zipWith (mergeRight)))

getAll ()
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (err => console .log (`Error: ${err}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {apply, zipWith, mergeRight} = R </script>
```

Ori Drori's solution is more flexible, allowing you to pass any number of `Promises`  for arrays of objects and it will return you a `Promise` for an array of merged objects.  The clever bit is the use of `transpose` to flip the array of arrays on its side to allow the use of `mergeAll`.

Mine is more specific to this problem, but it is easier to call, as it takes no parameters, and it generates those `Promise`s itself.  I use `zipWith` to take the two arrays returned and zip them together into a single array by calling `mergeRight` on each pair.

---

Also important to look at if you really want to pipe the result of one Promise's resolved value to another is [`pipeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith), which together with [`andThen`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#andThen) will let you build the sort of pipeline the title led to to expect.  But it's no real help for this problem, which is all about combining the results of multiple concurrent `Promise`s.

---

### Update

A comment asked the following, and my response is too large to respond in a comment:

> to fully grasp this in, which ever value is returned in `then()` which in this case is an array of promises. is/are fed into `apply` which in turns passes it to `zipWith` and so on ? or is it more of the opposite way -> right to left ?

I think neither is really the way to think about it.

Although these are not the exact implementations, we can think of those Ramda functions as looking like this:

```js
const apply = (fn) => (xs) => fn (...xs)
const zipWith = (fn) => (xs, ys) => xs .map ((_, i) => fn (xs [i], ys [i])
const mergeRight = (x, y) => Object .assign ({}, x, y)
```

So `apply` is a function decorator, which takes a function that accepts a number of arguments, and returns a function that takes those same arguments *as an array* instead.

`zipWith` takes a function and returns a function that takes two arrays, zipping them together by applying that function index-by-index.

And `mergeRight` accepts two objects and performs a shallow merge on them, returning a new object.

This means that `zipWith (mergeRight)` takes two arrays, and zips them together by performing an index-by-index shallow merge.

And `apply (zipWith (mergeRight))` alters that so that instead of two separate input arrays, it takes an *array* holding two arrays that will will zip with a shallow merge.

We will call it inside `.then()` because the `Promise .all` call returns a Promise that will resolve with an array containing the array results of your two calls.

This is roughly equivalent:

```js
.then (([xs, ys]) => xs .map ((_, i) => Object .assign ({}, xs [i], ys [i])))
```

The thought is that once you understand the functions, this is significantly more readable:

```js
.then (apply (zipWith (mergeRight)))
```

and we can see a chain of equivalent expressions by substitutions:

```js
/* 1: */ .then (([xs, ys]) => xs .map ((_, i) => Object .assign ({}, xs [i], ys [i])))
/* 2: */ .then (([xs, ys]) => xs .map ((_, i) => mergeRight (xs [i], ys [i])))
/* 3: */ .then (([xs, ys]) => zipWith (mergeRight) (xs, ys))
/* 4: */ .then (apply (zipWith (mergeRight)))
```

I hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: Much obliged, I appreciate the points you've pointed out. I did refactor pointed parts of my code and it really did start to make much more sense now. i noticed that upon merging the two responses the `id`s overlapped. mongoDB one being `_id` and cms is `id`.

Comment: to fully grasp this in, which ever value is returned in `then()` which in this case is an array of promises. is/are fed into apply which in turns passes it to `zipWith` and so on ? or is it more of the opposite way -> right to left ?

Comment: Added an update responding to the most recent comment.